# How to replace a div tag in my view using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to replace a div tag on my Images index page using Ajax. Right now, I have the following:

**_sub.html.erb**

```
<% @group.images.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image.pic.url(:medium) %>
      <%= button_to '+1', image_upvote_path(image), remote: true, method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="next_group">
    <%= render 'sub' %>
</div>
```

**upvote.js.erb**

```
$("#next_group").empty();
$("#next_group").append("<%= j render 'sub' %>");
```

**In my images_controller**

```
def index
    @group = Group.offset(rand(Group.count)).first
end

def upvote
    @image = Image.find(params[:image_id])
    @image.votes.create

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to groups_path  }
        format.js
    end
end
```

**And in my routes, I have**

```
image_upvote POST   /images/:image_id/upvote(.:format) images#upvote
```

**My understanding of what is going on:**

On my index page I have a div container that renders the sub partial that I want users to see. Inside the sub partial, I have a button_to helper that has the `remote: true` attribute(?) included as well as the path/action that clicking that button will initiate. The action is the `images#upvote`. So in the images controller, I define what I want to happen when the button is clicked (an upvote is created), but I also say that I want it to respond with Ajax, which happens because I've declared `remote: true`.

Here's where I start getting a little confused. Since Ajax is being used, does rails automatically look for the `upvote.js.erb` file since it's the upvote action that is occurring?

**My problem** right now is that the vote is being created just fine, but I don't think the javascript in `upvote.js.erb` is being executed. The page will stay on the current @group that is being displayed, without rendering a new `_sub` partial. So I guess I'm not sure if there is a problem with the javascript, or maybe something with the way I have the controller, views, and routes set up.

Comment: Add an `alert` or `console.log` statement to your `js.erb` file to test whether the code inside is getting executed.

Comment: I have tried with an `alert` on there. Nothing shows up. I removed the `alert` when I posted the question though

Comment: Why are you rendering to html? I'd remove the html response and just let rails default to the js.erb. If that works, you'll need to redirect using js, otherwise you're calling render twice in one request, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe button not belongs to any form, try using `link_to` or add `remote` options to the path